# How do we sync code between local machine and Azure VM?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm completely new to Azure. I have the code on my machine, and have created a Linux VM on Azure. Now, how do I use the GPU service to train my model? How do I sync the code between local machine and VM? I know this is very open question, but I went through docs and couldn't understand much.

Answer (score 0):

Really hard to guess what you really mean... I go ahead and assume what you need is something like the Azure Machine Learning service. This allows you to write your ML training code for example on your laptop and submit it to train on GPU-enabled VMs in Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-set-up-training-targets#amlcompute

See full examples here (look for others in the same github repo): https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/training/train-on-amlcompute/train-on-amlcompute.ipynb

I suggest you walk through the tutorials to get a basic understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You sync your code by implementing a CI/CD pipeline.

You commit your code, your build task will then package it up and your deploy task will then push that code to your virtual machine.

These links should help understand:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/solutions/architecture/cicd-for-azure-vms/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops-project/azure-devops-project-github

https://microsoft.github.io/PartsUnlimitedMRP/cicd/200.3x-CICD-CDwithLocalAgent.html